# Android SDK cant install a package

Tags: android, sdk, package

When i want to install a package, it doesnt have error and packages start to install but it doesnt finish just stop. What do you think where the problem is?

Comment: I think the problem is that you didn't provide enough information for the community to be able to help you. Sarcasm apart, are you under a proxy?

Comment: Operating System? SDK version? Which package? More info pls!!!

Comment: Ok. Win32 and I cannot install any version and all of packages. but it does not have any errors just stop and not finish

Answer (score 1):

Right click on android sdk manager and "**Run As Administrator**".